# Apply a function to two DataFrame columns and create new column from result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, difflib

I am working on a `pandas.DataFrame` using `python 3.5` with the following columns:

```
dataframe.head(2)

    TwitterID      Fullname    Gender    City     Screen_Name   
0     12345       John Smith     M      London     J_smith47  
1     25486       Emily Reid     F      Brighton   emreid_uk
       ...
```

I want to use the feature `screen_name` and to do so, was thinking about getting a result using *SequenceMatcher* to determine how 'close' the screen name was to the actual full name.

I am trying to apply the following function to all the values in `Fullname` and `Screen_Name` in order to get a score of how 'similar' these two features are and add a new column with this score to the `DataFrame`.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    x = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    score = x*100
    results = round(score, 2)
    return results

for column in dataframe:
    column[4] = similar(dataframe['Fullname'], dataframe['Screen_Name'])

dataframe.head(40)
```

I used a for loop as the data I work with is not very large. The function does work when I input strings but unfortunately this does not seem to work for me with the `DataFrame`.

Any pointer toward the right direction with this would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do instead:

```
def similar(row):
    x = SequenceMatcher(None, row['FullName'], row['ScreenName']).ratio()
    score = x*100
    results = round(score, 2)
    return results

dataframe['result'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: similar(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your help! I have tried this function and for some reason it return the address of the function in my dataframe instead of the value; '<function similar at 0x0BF8D9C0>'. Do you know why this happens by any chance?

Comment: I think you've missed the parentheses by accident and the shell just tells you what `similar` is (a function) instead of running it.

Comment: Yes, that would explain it.

Comment: Yes my bad I was using : _dataframe['result'] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: similar(), axis=1)_. Thanks a lot for your help to both of you.